# Why does work registers in ASM has matching uses?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

in assembler
we say that the EAX registers is an accumulator register to do calculations
but yet I can put whatever I want in EAX when I make a MOV, why do we say that then?

Comment: You don't say that :) There are architectures where you do have an accumulator but x86 is not such. That said, there are certain instructions and addressing modes that restrict which registers you can use.

Comment: What ? i don’t understand. didnyou say that in x86 i can put whatever i want in the EAX register ?

Comment: You say that certain instructions resteicts which register i can use, but what the « instruction » word  refers to ?

Comment: Yes you can put whatever you want in `eax`. x86 has what's called "general purpose registers", or GPRs for short. Arithmetic and most (integer) instructions work with any of those. But there are instructions that use particular registers implicitly. e.g. the string instructions use `esi` and `edi`, `loop` uses `ecx`, stack operations use `esp` and so on. Also in 16 bit mode your addressing modes are restricted.

Comment: See also https://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html.  I also marked this as a duplicate of several existing Q&As that explain what @Jester did in comments.

Answer (score -2):

if we have to add two numbers in must we have first MOV its and after adding the number. so we have got a result. if we have not MOV so it's not adding in a two number.